# pcl_visualization depend on non-existent package eigen

Tags: pcl, eigen, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using rosmake to build this package ,the following errors occured.One of these errors is "eigen" not exist,so I searched it and found it had been already replaced.
If you were saw this problem before,or you know how to do about it ,help me please!

```
mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package pcl_visualization
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests pcl_visualization
  [rospack] **Error: package/stack pcl_visualization depends on non-existent package eigen**


  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):


    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'pcl_visualization'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.
    Please fix the broken dependency!

  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:5 (rosbuild_init)

  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization/build/CMakeCache.txt
  CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35145/pcl_visualization-depend-on-non-existent-package-eigen/) by [Human](https://answers.ros.org/users/2483/human/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does [this](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/fuerte%282f%29Migration.html#Eigen_can.27t_be_found) fix it?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0